# How to go about temporarily disabling McAfee Internet Security?

Tags: windows-7, security, anti-virus

I have installed McAfee Internet Security on my Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) PC, but I need to install some drivers and I am afraid McAfee Internet Security will interfere with the installation process.

So, can someone please tell me how I can go about temporarily disabling it?

Comment: Did you search for "disable mcaffee"

Comment: Yeah, I found an answer [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-McAfee). If anybody wants to duplicate that answer on this site I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How I can go about temporarily disabling it?

> 1. Double-click the McAfee icon in the System Tray.
>
>    - This is located in the lower-right corner of the desktop.
>    - The icon looks like an "M" in a red shield.
>    - If you don't see the icon, click the arrow button at the edge of the System Tray to expand the Tray and display all the icons.
> 2. Click "Real-Time Scanning".
>
>    - This button is located at the top of the window, underneath the green banner.
>    - By default, it will say "On".
> 3. Disable Real-Time Scanning.
>
>    - When you click the button, you will be given the option to disable the real-time scanning, and allow you to set how long you want it
>        disabled.
>    - You should never go too long without active protection, so make sure that it is scheduled to turn back on as soon as you are done with your
>        task.
> 4. Turn off the Firewall.
>
>    - If you need to disable McAfee's Firewall, you can do so in a similar way.
>    - Click the "Firewall" button on the McAfee control panel, located beneath the "Real-Time Scanning" button.
>    - You can schedule how long the Firewall is disabled for. Just like real-time scanning, this should not be disabled any longer than it has
>        to.
>    - If you have a program that needs to bypass the Firewall, consider opening ports instead of disabling the entire firewall

Source [How to Disable McAfee](http://www.wikihow.com/Disable-McAfee)

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on Virus and Spyware Protection.
2. Click on Real-Time Scanning
3. Click on Turn Off.